# Random Top query in MongoDB using C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, random, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to take a record randomly from MongoDB using Linq in C#. Here is what I'm doing.

```
public string RandomWord()
{
    using (Mongo mongo = new Mongo(_mongoConfig.BuildConfiguration()))
    {
        try
        {
            mongo.Connect();
            var db = mongo.GetDatabase(_dbName);
            IMongoCollection<dic_words> collection = db.GetCollection<dic_words>();
            return 
                (from w in collection.Linq()
                where w.word.Length > 2
                orderby Guid.NewGuid()
                select w).Take(1).FirstOrDefault().word;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the error I got

> The query is too complex to be processed by MongoDB. Try building a map-reduce query by hand or simplifying the query and using Linq-to-Objects.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that now that official C# driver has LINQ support you should probably switch from using FluentMongo which is no longer supported.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991722/transition-from-fluent-mongo-to-mongo-c-sharp-1-4-driver for more info.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using FluentMongo - the error you got is coming from there.

The likely candidate to cause this error is this line:

```
   orderby Guid.NewGuid()
```

This does not appear to be supported with FluentMongo.   It means you probably want to use a different method of randomizing the returned record.  FluentMongo does support OrderBy but [their documentation](https://github.com/craiggwilson/fluent-mongo/wiki/Linq) only mentions ability to sort by field.

Note that something that maps from LINQ to SQL will not necessarily map to MongoDB query.
Some related discussion about this is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648196/random-row-from-linq-to-sql) and many others.

By the way, there is a lot of discussion about how to get a random document/object back from MongoDB, both on SO and on mongo-users list.  There is even a [write-up of it](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/random-attribute/) in Mongo Cookbook.  I would recommend reviewing those for possible solution to your use case.

Comment: I developed a custom solution. Added all Id to cacheable List and get random one to send a query to db.